# Fluid is not simulated at the target location

Tags: fluid-simulation

I've tried to set the S mesh to be a fluid or inflow object and have created a large size domain around it. However, the fluid is generated in the top left corner instead of around the S mesh.

How do I make the S become a fluid?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Origin point of the fluid object was set putside/on edge of the domain.